# Use @RequestScoped and @Produces to Inject User Entity into the Jersey handler

Tags: java, rest, jersey, ejb, cdi

User Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public List<Site> sites;
```

Facade class to access database:

```
@Stateless
public class UserFacade extends AbstractFacade<User, Long> {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    ...
}
```

Resource class for User injection:

```
@RequestScoped
public class Resource {

    @Inject
    UserFacade userFacade;

    @Inject
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Produces
    public User getUser() {
        final String name = request.getUserPrincipal().getName();
        // ... find user in database ...
    }

}
```

And Jersey handler:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/sites")
public class Sites {    

    @EJB
    SiteFacade siteFacade;

    @Inject
    User user;

    ...
```

Here is the problem now:

When I want to access user.sites list, I'm getting lazy load exception. But apparently because User injected by RequestScoped provider, it should refresh per request with same EntityManager session. Right?

Is there anyway I inject User Entity per rest request into Rest handler class?

Comment: Show us the *// ... find user in database ...* code

Answer (score 1):

The `EntityManager` is bound to the transaction, not to the request scope.

So the `User` producer method and your `Sites` business method are called in two distinct transactions, which explains the `LazyLoadException`.

Comment: Is there anyway to manage this situation? Before I use EJB, I did it with create a ServletFilter to commit the transition after servlet call (not using JTA). So, I had zero or one transaction per request and it was very easy to handle these problems.